# Is it possible to change the generation location of a nuget package? .Net Core 5 Visual Studio 19

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-5.0

I have an application that generate a local nuget package, and this nuget package i have to install in another application.

So i would like to change the folder that is generate the nuget package from application\bin\debug to c:\Nugets. Is it possible?

Comment: Certainly with `dotnet pack` you just specify the output directory with `-o`. But we don't know *how* your application is generating the NuGet package, which makes it harder to know whether that helps you. Please provide more context.

Comment: in the project properties I checked the option to generate the nuget package in the "Package" section, which by default generates the nuget package in the project's "debug" folder.

Comment: Okay, so when you say "I have an application that generate a local nuget package" you mean you have a project which represents a package, and building in Visual Studio creates the package? I have an idea - I'm just trying it now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the `PackageOutputPath` property in the csproj file. For example:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <PackageOutputPath>c:\Nugets</PackageOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

At the very least, that makes `dotnet pack` place the package in `c:\Nugets` - I'd expect it to do the same from Visual Studio too.